# ActiveMQ Artemis cluster on Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, activemq-artemis, jgroups

I am trying to setup simple cluster of 2 ActiveMQ Artemis brokers within Docker Swarm environment.

**Stack configuration**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    broker_1:
        image: broker-local
        build:
            context: ./activemq
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-centos
        ports:
            - "8161:8161" # Embedded web server
            - "61616:61616" # Main Artemis acceptor
        networks:
            artemis-cluster-network:
        environment:
            EXTRA_ARGS: "--http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia"
            ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "true"
        configs:
            -   source: broker_1_config
                target: /run/config/broker.xml

    broker_2:
        image: broker-local
        depends_on:
            - "broker_1"
        build:
            context: ./activemq
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-centos
        ports:
            - "8162:8161" # Embedded web server
            - "61617:61617" # Main Artemis acceptor
        networks:
            artemis-cluster-network:
        environment:
            EXTRA_ARGS: "--http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia"
        configs:
            -   source: broker_2_config
                target: /run/config/broker.xml

networks:
    artemis-cluster-network:
        driver: overlay
        attachable: true

configs:
    broker_1_config:
        file: ./broker_1.xml
    broker_2_config:
        file: ./broker_2.xml
```

**Broker_1 configuration**

```xml
   <configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
      <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

         <name>broker_1</name>

         <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>

         <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>

         <large-messages-directory>./data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

         <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>

         <!-- Connectors -->

         <connectors>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</connector>
            <!-- connector to the server1 -->
            <connector name="server2-connector">tcp://broker_2:61617</connector>
         </connectors>

         <!-- Acceptors -->
         <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</acceptor>
         </acceptors>

         <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
               <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
               <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
               <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
               <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
               <max-hops>5</max-hops>
               <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
                  <connector-ref>server2-connector</connector-ref>
               </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
         </cluster-connections>

         <!-- Other config -->

         <security-settings>
            <!--security for example queue-->
            <security-setting match="exampleQueue">
               <permission roles="guest" type="createDurableQueue"/>
               <permission roles="guest" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
               <permission roles="guest" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
               <permission roles="guest" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
               <permission roles="guest" type="consume"/>
               <permission roles="guest" type="send"/>
            </security-setting>
         </security-settings>

         <addresses>
            <address name="exampleQueue">
               <anycast>
                  <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
               </anycast>
            </address>
         </addresses>

         <broker-plugins>
            <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
               <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
               <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
               <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
               <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
               <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
               <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
               <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            </broker-plugin>
         </broker-plugins>
      </core>
   </configuration>
```

**Broker_2 configuration**

```xml
  <configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
     <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <name>broker_2</name>

        <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>./data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

        <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>

        <!-- Connectors -->
        <connectors>
           <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617</connector>
           <!-- connector to the server0 -->
           <connector name="server1-connector">tcp://broker_1:61616</connector>
        </connectors>

        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
           <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <cluster-connections>
           <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
              <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
              <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
              <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
              <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
              <max-hops>5</max-hops>
              <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
                 <connector-ref>server1-connector</connector-ref>
              </static-connectors>
           </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <!-- Other config -->

        <security-settings>
           <!--security for example queue-->
           <security-setting match="exampleQueue">
              <permission roles="guest" type="createDurableQueue"/>
              <permission roles="guest" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
              <permission roles="guest" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
              <permission roles="guest" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
              <permission roles="guest" type="consume"/>
              <permission roles="guest" type="send"/>
           </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <addresses>
           <address name="exampleQueue">
              <anycast>
                 <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
              </anycast>
           </address>
        </addresses>

        <broker-plugins>
           <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
              <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
              <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
              <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
              <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
              <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
              <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
              <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
           </broker-plugin>
        </broker-plugins>
     </core>
  </configuration>
```

After running both services nothing happens. Nothing interesting is logged.

I tried UDP discovery approach but found out that is not possible on Docker Overlay Network.

Then I tried JGroups approach which did not work also. There were attempts to establish connection but every attempt timed out. And attempts were made to hosts represented by container ID.
This approach could be interesting but shared ping directory which is used by JGRoups is not valid for Swarm approach. On local machine it was not problem to share it between two containers.

Also I am using Fiddler so names like broker_1 are translated to localhost.

Comment: When you say you "tried JGroups" what JGroups configuration(s) did you try? If you only tried the directory ping configuration it's not surprising that it didn't work. Check out [this documentation](https://github.com/belaban/jgroups-docker) for more details on how to configure JGroups for Docker use-cases.

Comment: @JustinBertram Sorry for late response. Tried suggestion from first comment and it worked so thanks a lot. As to your second comment. Indeed I tried directory ping approach. I saw requests in logs but targets in those request were docker container ids. Although I have no need for dynamic discovery It would be nice to see it work within docker swarm.

Comment: I converted my first comment into an answer. If you mark it as correct that will help other folks who run into this same issue in the future.

Comment: @JustinBertram Of course. I wanted to suggest to you to do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connector` named "netty-connector" shouldn't use `0.0.0.0`. This is the address that will be sent to other nodes in the cluster to tell them how to connect back to the node who sent it. The address `0.0.0.0` will be meaningless in that context. It needs to be the actual IP address or hostname where the broker is listening for network connections.

Comment: In the question broker files the connector name is "netty-connector" and not "netty_connection".